# VueJS watcher out of memory crash

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

**Problem**

My team and I are working on a project for our company, we are developing the frontend of this project in VueJS + NuxtJS + Vuetify, so far everything was good, we deployed the project today and strangest thing took us by surprise, while the project is working perfectly in the local environment, if you try to access it the deployed production version, it doesn't render, instead the browser gets frozen.

**Details**

After some debugging, we found out Chrome was pausing the project given a possible memory crash, as shown in the following image.

[image: Chrome dev tools showing the crash]

We decided to start debugging deeper, and we found out the error was:

[image: Error after debugging]

Which makes reference to the function `cleanupDeps()` from the vue watcher.

**Questions**

My questions are:

- Why is this happening only on production and not development (talking about nuxtjs environments and webpack compilation)
- Is there anyone else who faced this in the past? (I've been researching in Github issues and internet in general and haven't found nothing, that's why I'm posting this question here.)

Thank you very much in advance if someone manages to solve this.

**Update on issue found**

After some more investigation after I posted the question, I found out that the error was being provoked by Vuetify tabs, the why, we still don't know but this is a detail that scopes the question a little bit more.

[image: Vuetify tabs component]

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: we are not able to identify where is it exactly because is coming from VueJS itself, the error is coming from here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/1762a66204d4856e0725f09f12e4da16f403bf09/src/core/observer/watcher.js#L142

Comment: Are you able to test it in another browser? Just to see if it's Chrome specific or not.

Comment: Nope, I tested in all 3 (Chrome, Firefox and Safari), and even in Edge and doesn't work, gets frozen and eventually shows the error that the tab is dead.

Comment: Could be related to [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1695) or [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/805)?